# Multiple server cluster setup. How do I track which server is connecting to the parent mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, cluster-computing

I have a setup of 12 download servers, they all have their ip and login details in a mysql database on my database server.

The database has a dlserver_details table with following fields:

id, server name, location, domain, ip address, additional ips

Each row in this table has a specific server's records.
How do I find out which server is connecting to the mysql so that mysql can send the correct server's information?

For example if Server A is connecting to mysql through remote sql, there is no way of knowing which row belongs to Server A.

The solution I came up with 4 years ago was to assign each server an id manually and save it in a file called config.php
When the server wants to fetch its details from the mysql db, it sends query like:

```
$serverid = 4;
SELECT * from dlserver_details where id = $serverid
```

Which works perfectly fine.
But the problem is that this solution is not very efficient as we are scaling up. Whenever we add servers to the cluster, we have to modify some files and the database. This slows things down as the files are synced automatically to all the download servers then I have to manually assign the correct server id and update its records in the database.

Is there a proper solution to this? Like Can I track with mysql which host is connecting to it for the query so that it can look for the correct record for that host on its own?

Something like:

lets say mysql ip is 1.1.1.1 and client server ip is 2.2.2.2

row in the table:

```
id = 4
ip = 2.2.2.2
servername = Server A

Query: SELECT * FROM dlserver_details WHERE ip = CONNECTING_HOST_IP
```

Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing it with:

```
... WHERE ip = (Select SUBSTRING_INDEX(host, ':', 1) From information_schema.processlist WHERE ID = connection_id())
```